# What does "couldn't possibly <do something>" mean?

Tags: adverbs, negation

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/day#late_idmg_7):

1. *He started working hard much too late in the day — he couldn't **possibly** catch up*.

My variants:

2. *He started working hard much too late in the day — he **possibly** couldn't catch up*.
3. *He started working hard much too late in the day — he couldn't catch up*.

I can understand (2) and (3) but I cannot understand (1) because when I begin translating "*not possibly*" (from "*he could not possibly catch up*") into my language I get something meaningless.
Could you help me please?

Comment: #1 means the same as #3, and #2 leaves some doubt. It was not possible to catch up.

Comment: @WeatherVane Why is (1) equal to (3)? Why does "_possibly_" in (1) not convey any meaning? Thanks!

Comment: It adds stress to the idea: He couldn't [possibly] catch up. The negative applies to "catch up" not to "possibly", which is an adverb. Compare "He could possibly catch up" with "He could not possibly catch up".

Comment: _It was not possible for him to catch up_.

Comment: @WeatherVane If <the negative applies to "_catch up_" not to "_possibly_"> then we can take out "_possibly_" from "_could not possibly catch up_", thereby getting "_possibly could not catch up_" as in (2), i.e. by this logic (1) = (2). But you said it isn't so. I'm confused.

Comment: Don't attempt to "translate" ***not possibly***. That's what's leading you to the totally non-idiomatic form in your example #2. The negation attaches to ***could not***, as can easily be established simply by noting that #3 (which doesn't even include the word ***possibly***) means essentially the same thing as #1. Note that ***possibly*** here is just an optional "intensifier" (effectively meaning ***under any conceivable circumstances***).

Comment: In #2 the 'possibly' has been repositioned and now modifies "could not" instead of "catch up".

Comment: @WeatherVane: Indeed. So if we *had* to "interpret" #2, we'd say it means ***perhaps he wouldn't be able to catch up***. But that makes no sense in conjunction with the preceding clause, let alone that it's not really an idiomatic construction in the first place.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree, #2 seems to be OP's (mis-)construction as to what #1 might mean.

Comment: @WeatherVane You said: the negative applies to "_catch up_" not to "_possibly_". But as I understood, "_he couldn't possibly catch up_" = "_it was **not possible** for him to catch up_" or literally "_it was **not possible** that he could catch up_". That is, we took out "_not possible_" from the clause. Therefore you were wrong: the negative applies to "possibly". Do you agree?

Comment: No, I don't agree. Please read what @FumbleFingers wrote about "not possibly".

Comment: @WeatherVane  As far as I could understand, FumbleFingers wrote we should perceive "_possibly_" in "_he couldn't possibly catch up_" not as its usual meaning "_perhaps_" but as another meaning "_under any conceivable circumstances_". It is a useful answer to me but it looks more like an attempt to avoid finding a logic.

Comment: FF wrote *Don't attempt to translate **not possibly**.*

Answer (score 6):

Don't break up 'couldn't possibly' into could/not/possibly and then translate each word. Just consider that the 'can' verb is being emphasised.

When we follow the negative forms of the verb can/could with 'possibly' we are emphasising that we can (or could not) do something.

I can't possibly be there by midday! (I definitely can't be there by midday')

I couldn't possibly finish my homework last night, because my dog died.

This also applies to hypothetical uses of 'could':

I couldn't possibly go to the mayor's house, because he is a Nazi.

> possibly adverb (WITH CAN/COULD)
>
> **used with "can" or "could" for emphasis:**
> He can't possibly have drunk all that on his own!
> We did all that we possibly could to persuade her to come.
>
> **used in polite requests:**
> Could I possibly ask you to move your chair a little?
>
> **used when politely refusing offers:**
> "Have another chocolate." "No, really,
> I couldn't possibly."

[Possibly (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/possibly)

Answer (score 2):

(1) means the same as (3).

There's a possible confusion here because of the different ways that "can/could" behave compared to "may/might". If you apply a negative to "may" or "might", it means "possibly not". But if you apply a negative to "can" or "could", it means "not possible". If you understand algebraic notation, this might help visualize it:

*possibly not catch up:*
may + (not catch up)
might + (not catch up)

*not possible to catch up:*
(cannot) + catch up
(could not) + catch up

The word order doesn't change. It's simply a property of the words "can" and "could" that negations apply to the modal verb, not the main verb, whereas with "may" and "might", negations apply to the main verb. This means word-for-word translations of sentences with "can/could" or "may/might" will necessarily result in failure.